# How to solve Twig_Error_Runtime in Symfony 3

Tags: symfony, twig, profiler, symfony-3.3, php-7.1

I have inherited a rather complicated Symfony 3 project (I'm using Laravel mostly nowadays - it's been years since I used Symfony) so this is a bit out of my wheelhouse.

**I did a composer update and it built ok.**

```
composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 0 installs, 1 update, 0 removals
  - Updating twig/twig 1.x-dev (e8555dc => 1445246):  Checking out 1445246d8e
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
> Incenteev\ParameterHandler\ScriptHandler::buildParameters
Updating the "app/config/parameters.yml" file
> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap
> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache

 // Clearing the cache for the dev environment with debug
 // true


 [OK] Cache for the "dev" environment (debug=true) was successfully cleared.


> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::installAssets

 Trying to install assets as relative symbolic links.

 -- -------- ----------------
     Bundle   Method / Error
 -- -------- ----------------


 [OK] All assets were successfully installed.


> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile
> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget
```

**I cleared the cache**

```
php bin/console cache:clear --no-warmup --env local
```

**When I browse to my local development URL, I get:**

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

(4/4) Twig_Error_Runtime
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Undefined offset: 0").

in exception_full.html.twig (line 1)
at Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(array('status_code' => 500, 'status_text' => 'Internal Server Error', 'exception' => object(FlattenException), 'logger' => object(Logger), 'currentContent' => '', 'app' => object(AppVariable)), array('head' => array(object(__TwigTemplate_ed2c7b0206a4a8ba0c01ceb7e7a7f0ba342d3cbf55c912fe1f34e6abd35411c0), 'block_head'), 'title' => array(object(__TwigTemplate_ed2c7b0206a4a8ba0c01ceb7e7a7f0ba342d3cbf55c912fe1f34e6abd35411c0), 'block_title'), 'body' => array(object(__TwigTemplate_ed2c7b0206a4a8ba0c01ceb7e7a7f0ba342d3cbf55c912fe1f34e6abd35411c0), 'block_body')))
in Template.php (line 403)

<snip/>

(3/4) ContextErrorException
Notice: Undefined offset: 0

in Profiler.php (line 23)
at Twig_Extension_Profiler->enter(object(Twig_Profiler_Profile))
in ProfilerExtension.php (line 40)

<snip/>

(2/4) Twig_Error_Runtime
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Undefined offset: 0").

in base.html.twig (line 11)
at Twig_Template->displayBlock('javascripts', array('env' => 'local', 'app' => object(AppVariable)), array('title' => array(object(__TwigTemplate_e199b3b21ccad34239564ea288dce2bfa2f11212622c2c75863848c603e82b70), 'block_title'), 'stylesheets' => array(object(__TwigTemplate_e199b3b21ccad34239564ea288dce2bfa2f11212622c2c75863848c603e82b70), 'block_stylesheets'), 'body' => array(object(__TwigTemplate_888836406c51f4232014f646f747310c541800b61ef418c11fbfcee42a1afe9b), 'block_body'), 'javascripts' => array(object(__TwigTemplate_e199b3b21ccad34239564ea288dce2bfa2f11212622c2c75863848c603e82b70), 'block_javascripts')))
in Environment.php(467) : eval()'d code (line 51)

<snip/>

(1/4) ContextErrorException
Notice: Undefined offset: 0

in Profiler.php (line 23)
at Twig_Extension_Profiler->enter(object(Twig_Profiler_Profile))
in ProfilerExtension.php (line 40)
```

Since this appears to be an issue with vendor files, I'm not sure where to go from here.

The last error in the logs is

```
[2018-03-02 15:56:53] request.CRITICAL: Exception thrown when handling an exception (Twig_Error_Runtime: An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Undefined offset: 0"). at /Projects/myproject/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/Resources/views/Exception/exception_full.html.twig line 1) {"exception":"[object] (Twig_Error_Runtime(code: 0): An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template (\"Notice: Undefined offset: 0\"). at /Projects/myproject/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/Resources/views/Exception/exception_full.html.twig:1, Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\ContextErrorException(code: 0): Notice: Undefined offset: 0 at /Projects/myproject/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Profiler.php:23)"} []
```

Comment: Hi. Did you try to use current version of twig? In your `composer.json` type `"twig/twig": "^1.0||^2.0"`.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add this line in composer.json
"twig/twig": "2.4.4"

For me worked.
It seems the last updates for twig 2.4.5 had this problem.

I found the answer here:
https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/issues/2627